# Does Authorize.net support different currency types?

Tags: currency, authorize.net

I have found a post referencing a field for Authorize.net called "x_currency_type", however the Authorize.net API documentation does not reference anything about currency type.   I also found a post that makes it clear that Authorize.Net ONLY supports USD.

I am confused. Does Authorize support setting up recuring payments using other currency, if yes can anyone please help me how to use that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorize.Net just announced [support for the Canadian Dollar, British Pound, and Euro](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/Authorize-Net-Expansion-into-Canada-the-United-Kingdom-and/td-p/33690).

**Currency Code Updates**

If your integration uses AIM, SIM or DPM and sends the “x_currency_code” field with a value of “USD,” you may need to make a small change to support processing in CAD, GBP or EUR. You will now need to send the appropriate currency code that correlates to the currency that the merchant is set up to process in. For example, you must send “CAD” for any merchant you set up to process in Canadian Dollars.

If you’re not sending the currency code, or if you’re using any of our other Authorize.Net APIs, no changes are required at this time. The currency code for those APIs will automatically default to the currency associated with the merchant’s processor.

**Additional Required Fields**

In order to accept payments through our new processor connections in Europe, some of the existing, optional fields are now required with each transaction. Please review the following list of additional required fields for processing GBP or EUR payments:

First Name
Last Name
Address
City
State
Zip
Country
Email

The API guides that these changes apply to have been updated accordingly.

Comment: i get the following error "The supplied currency code is either invalid, not supported, not allowed for this merchant or doesn't have an exchange rate." i used Authorize.Net's Advanced Integration Method (AIM)
API (version 3.1)

Comment: You should contact their support and see which of those cases are the cause of you error. If you haven't set up an exchange rate that probably would do it.

Comment: they mentioned in documentation "Affiliates Program Updates" its mean i need to signup or renew my account?? currently i m using test account

Comment: I don't *think* so. But it's so new that it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Authorize.net fully live with GBP(pounds), Euros and USD. However their test environment is only displaying in USD at the moment. However the integration to Authorize.Net is the same regardless of currency.  So when using their test account, make sure we are not sending any currencies other than USD.

Comment: Sorry, is that meant to be the answer? That multi-currency does not work in the sanbox environment?  Your answer is not very easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

I tried changing the currency in Woocommerce but not working when I test.

Suddenly, I change the customer details from Philippines to US. It payment went successful.

Maybe the currency will also check the location of the buyer.